# File upload is not working with Java Selenium sendkeys in Jenkins run but its working in locally

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

When I am trying to upload a new file using Sendkeys in selenium with Java, its working in locally but if I am running the same script in Jenkins server, getting the exception as 'org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: File not found :'.

Below is the code snippet which I have written to get the path of the file and passing the file path using sendkeys.

```
private void bulkUpload(String filePath, By locator) throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement input = action.findWebElement(locator, "Upload");
    JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor) action.getWebDriver();
    jsx.executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", input);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    input.sendKeys(filePath);
  }
```

Thanks in Advance for your help
[image: Jenkins Console]

Answer (score 1):

Try it with this solution below I had the same problem and solved it this way

*(if u have class cast exception on output , try to get Web Element inside method that upload file)

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("file-upload"));
LocalFileDetector detector = new LocalFileDetector();
String path =new File("src/test/resources/testdata/sampleDocument.docx").getAbsolutePath();
File file = detector.getLocalFile(path);
((RemoteWebElement) element).setFileDetector(detector);
element.sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

vsreekanth try send the absolute file path.
I've been using it that way and it works locally and at Jenkins.

I hope it works for you.

**path** parameter is a file in the resources, such as: `"src/main/resources/files/sampleFile.txt"`

```
public void uploadFile(WebElement input, String path) {
    WebElement btnUpload = input.findElement(By.xpath(".."))
            .findElement(By.xpath("..")).findElement(By.tagName("button"));
    String script = "arguments[0].style.display = 'block';";
    obtemJs().executeScript(script, input);
    input.sendKeys(new File(path).getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: Here what is 'obtemJs()'? What is the import to resolve this.

Comment: It's just a method to get the JavascriptExecutor ...


 public JavascriptExecutor obtemJs() {

  return (JavascriptExecutor) getWebDriver();

 }